# Meta title multi language website same keyword use

Tags: seo, meta-tags, multilingual, title

I have a website with multiple languages, but some of the most important keywords are the same/similar in the different languages. For the meta descriptions it's not a problem but the titles are very similar are there any rules for this?

Or can I for example solves this with hreflang tag in the links?
Any tips or advice would be very welcome

Answer (score 2):

It can cause a dilution effect but the dilution effect may not be enough to have any effect or create a problem. Generally, a similar page will appear as more from this site listing under the page which is deemed the most relevant. In other words, it is almost a search engine enhancement, gaining more exposure ... but it is not always good or bad ...

### What is the dilution effect?

One youtube (let us call him #1) noticed a dilution effect problem when they added recommended keywords to their local search. Initially, the traffic increased as the site could be found in more cities. But after time the traffic went down and was not as high as it was before adding the recommended words ... another example gives better insight.

Another youtube was trying to make the perfect money-making video, where he could advertise videos on his youtube video (selling advertisements on youtube), (Lets call him #2). The goal was to make a money-making video where he could purchase advertising to his video for less than the amount of money it was making per view.

Here we have the advantage of having youtube analytics to show us what is happening. The view from non-organic traffic was of less time and did not click through to his additional advertisements. Sadly he did not accomplish his goal.

But #2 ended up diluting his money-making video ... after he stopped buying the ads the views were abominable; because youtube weighs in view time and other statics in ranking a video. His money-making video was no longer getting what it had in terms of organic traffic. The advertisement views diluted his organic view time stats ... they did recover over time.

Lets go back to #1 although Google does not give us good analytics into the user behavior ... when person #1 added other cities to his local google account fewer people may have engaged with those listing and it effected the stats in a way that Google does not share. He diluted his listing.

### Solution to not dilute

In order to not dilute, change the keywords, amount of keywords, and or links or amount of links between the pages so the listing you want is pushed up and the one you don't want is pushed down, or target other keywords / keyword combinations on the other page.

On organic results, the dilution effect may not be that significant. Other factors that affect user behavior like low-quality content would be more important. And the enhancement of having the "more from this site" may get far greater at improving user behavior than the split in traffic between to competing pages.